# HttpsUrlConnection getting EOF exception while GET request

Tags: java, https, stream

I am getting some data from server with https. Problem is when I try to run this code it just writes empty string(`response.toString()` returns empty). But when I add `Thread.sleep` method before `BufferedReader` line, it just works perfect(returns full data from server). What is the main problem here?

```
   private static void httpGet(String urlStr, String[] paramName, String[] paramVal) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    HttpsURLConnection conn
            = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
    conn.setRequestProperty(COOKIE_HEADER, param);

    if (conn != null) {
    //Thread.sleep(1000);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
     System.out.println(response.toString());
    }
   }
```

Comment: What is your server code? This client code looks perfectly fine, so please post your server code, maybe the problem is there. Please also update this code to the full method, as this is only a snippet and something may lay in the envelope of this code.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki I didn't write the server code. I am getting some xml data from Nessus application. (https://discussions.tenable.com/docs/DOC-1172). When I post my login parameters, Nessus returns some session token. This part works without any problem but when I try to get some xml information from Nessus it just didn't works without Thread.sleep.

Comment: Try to remove the line "conn.setDoOutput(true); " if that will do no effect, then try with "conn.getOutputStream().flush();" instead of "Thread.sleep() "  , maybe that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code is working for me ;-) even w/o Thread.sleep - see below - I'm pulling data from "Oracle". Also please don't forget to close input stream.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class URLConnectionReader {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL("https://www.oracle.com");
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
    //conn.setRequestProperty("COOKIE_HEADER", param);

    if (conn != null) {
        // Thread.sleep(1000);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> `HttpsUrlConnection` getting EOF exception while GET request

You aren't doing a GET request. You are doing a POST, but you aren't providing any POST data.

There are numerous other issues here:

```
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

This is the default. Don't write pointless code.

```
conn.setDoOutput(true);
```

This changes the request method to POST. If you don't want to do a POST, remove this line.

```
conn.setDoInput(true);
```

This is the default. Don't write pointless code.

```
if (conn != null) {
```

`conn` cannot possibly be null at this point. Don't write pointless code.

```
//Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Sleeps in networking code are literally a waste of time. Don't use them, and don't ever think that they solve network problems. They don't. They might *mask* them for a bit, but the underlying problem remains.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
```

Here you are trying to read the response from a POST without ever having written any POST data. The server will probaby object to that, possibly by terminating the connection prematurely, which might cause an `EOFException`, but not in the `readLine()` code above. As you haven't provided a stack trace it is impossible to comment further. However your code should work after fixing the errors noted above, unless there is a server-side problem.

Comment: This code doesn't throw any exception but response.toString method returns empty string.(When I try use conn.getInputstream() I am getting end of file error) When I add thread.sleep method response.toString method returns data from server. I don't get why I need to add Thread.sleep? What Thread.sleep doing here?

Comment: You don't need to add `Thread.sleep()`. I've already said that. You need to fix several bugs which I have enumerated above. You have still not provided the stack trace that was requested.

Comment: And if the code doesn't throw any exception why does your question mention ' EOF exception'?